# run matlab subplot without opening figure

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have the following Matlab 2013b code:

```
subplot(2,2,1);plot(var([c1 c2],0,2)); title('var(c1,c2)');
subplot(2,2,2);plot(var([c3,c4],0,2));title('var(c3,c4)');
saveas(gcf,pth);
```

I would like to execute this code without opening a figure window in Matlab. 
Is this possible? If not, I would like the figure window to be minimized upon plotting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with a call to `figure` you can change the visibility:

```
figure('Visible','Off')
```

will create an invisible figure window.

The MATLAB documentation on [Figure properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html) also includes this warning:

> Changing the Visible property of a figure does not change the `Visible` property of its child components even though hiding the figure prevents its children from displaying.

Comment: Thank You..simple and to the point..